# NMSSH Linker errors when building for iOS Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I'm using [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) in my app, and I was having some problems. I've followed the installation procedure written in the GitHub page, and it works fine on the iOS6.1 simulator. However, when I build it onto an iPod touch device running iOS5.1, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_decomp in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_comp in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_dtor in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_init in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_dtor in NMSSH(comp.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      _comp_method_zlib_init in NMSSH(comp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

A suggestion from another SO thread said to include another libz, so I included libz.1.2.5.dylib and it ran without any errors. However, whenever I tried to send an SSH command from the app running on the actual device, it crashes without a trace. Doing so in the iOS6.1 Simulator results in no problems.

Any help would be much appreciated!
~Carpetfizz

EDIT: App also works fine on the iOS5.1 Simulator!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild the framework for the target device and re-add the .framework file to your Xcode project. Like so 
[image]

Then clean and build. Add the .framework file to your application project frameworks, first removing the old .framework file. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add **lib.dylib**.
Also add **CFNetworking**.
It's that simple.
Then it should work.
Hope this helped.